# DotNetNuke error

Tags: dotnetnuke

I hosted one `DotNetNUke Application` to my production server, and locally it works perfectly. But, when browsing it redirects to the error page.

How do I set the `default.aspx` as my application default page? I am getting the error as below:

```
DotNetNuke Error

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Windows Vista

 Return to Site
```

Can anyone can help me, please? Will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Hi, I changed the Path in the PortalAlias table to the server url and `default.aspx` as the starting page, but it displays the `error.aspx` as default page.

Please help me resolve this problem..

Comment: I have this exact problem. If I browse to default.aspx the site works fine. When I go to the root of the webite I end up at error.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

So, the application works perfectly locally, but not when you put it on the server.  Is that correct?

Make sure that your portal alias is valid.  If the site is hosted at
  http://www.mysite.com
then www.mysite.com needs to be listed in the PortalAlias table

If you open that table in SQL Mgmt Studio, you'll probably see an entry attaching the portal to your local DotNetNuke folder (ie. localhost).  Just add a new entry that points to the same PortalID, but with the correct URL for your production server.

---

Assuming your DNN installation is at "mysite.com", if you navigate to
    http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx
do you still get the error page?  If so is any error listed?

Comment: I changed the path in the portal alias table to server url but it can't working
Thank your for your suggesstion

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue (for me) by taking the web.config file from a working site with the same version of DotNetNuke and modifying it to have to correct machine key and connection strings. This is my last resort something is really strange procedure.